# Emiting QTableWidgetItem specific signal on being clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to implement the functionality that multiple QTableWidgetItems inside of a QTableWidget can be selected and unselected so that the values and "positions" of those QTableWidgetItems is known for further use.

Inside of the QTableWidget there are some empty cells, for aesthetics/spacing, which should be ignored by the functionality I'm trying to implement.
But that could also easily be done afterwards by checking if a selected item does have content.

```py
self.table_widget.itemClicked.connect(self.some_function)
```

Would be the signal best fitting but I cannot specify or know which item was clicked inside of the table widget or whether is was selected or unselected.

**Question: How do I implement the functionality to emit a specific signal when a specific QTableWidgetItem is pressed?**

---

Here some pseude code for use in examples:

```py
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("qtdesignerfile.ui", self)
        self.show()
        #connect signal to function
        self.table_widget.itemClicked.connect(self.some_function)
        #create "global" list to save all selected items
        self.selected_items = []

    #some function to execute the logic
    def some_function(self):
        #condition distinguishing if item was just selected or unselected
        if QTableWidgetItem(row, column) is not already selected:

            #change background color to indicate selection
            self.table_widget.item(row,column).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,100))
            #"format" information of clicked item for further use
            selected_item = [str(table_widget.item(row,column).text()), row, column]
            #"save" selected item in global list for further use
            self.selected_items.append(selected_item)

        #condition distinguishing if item was just selected or unselected
        if QTableWidgetItem(row, column) is already selected:

            #change background color to indicate un-selection 
            self.table_widget.item(row,column).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))
            #"format" information of clicked item for further use
            selected_item = [str(table_widget.item(row,column).text()), row, column]
            #remove the un-selected item from global list
            self.selected_items.remove(selected_item)
```

Example ui-file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>418</width>
    <height>297</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="table_widget">
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 1</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 2</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 3</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 4</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 5</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Row 6</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Grouping</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Column 2</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Column 3</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <property name="text">
        <string>category 1</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry (1,1)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(1,2)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(2,1)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(2,2)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <property name="text">
        <string>category 2</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(4,1)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(4,2)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(5,1)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Entry(5,2)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>418</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

I am really puzzled on how to easily implement this functionality and am open to suggestion on a different approach.

The user of the application should be able to select multiple QTableWidgetItems so that the information of the row the item is inside can be transferred to another QTableWidget for further use.

Comment: share `qtdesignerfile`

Comment: Okay, then I'll use a .ui created by me, if it doesn't work then you'll have to analyze where the fault is. I only have one doubt: Do the items in the QTableWidget have text or are they empty?

Comment: Could you create a .ui with just the QTableWidget? I think that .ui is going to have few lines, it also explains better what you mean by: *The user might select an empty item (empty row for spacing) but those should be ignored*

Comment: @eyllanesc added an example ui file

Comment: Great, could you explain your previous comment, I see empty items. Can those items be selected?

Comment: @eyllanesc Those items should be ignored by the functionality I'm trying to implement.

Comment: That you should point out in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc Added it to the question but I think that isn't that important as I could easily read out the item afterwards and if the item is empty I ignore it for further handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemClicked) signal does pass the element that is pressed if the element exists, by default Qt Designer only creates elements in which it edited, where appropriate where it placed text.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

SelectedRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("qtdesignerfile.ui", self)

        # self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem)
    def onClicked(self, it):
        state = not it.data(SelectedRole)
        it.setData(SelectedRole, state)
        it.setBackground(
            QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 100) if state else QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works perfectly and is way more elegant than I though would be possible.